# Fedora 23 has stopped installing new programs and updates

Tags: linux, installation, fedora, python

I have been using Fedora 23 for the last 2 months and since yesterday DNF has stopped installing or upgrading programs.

This is the error message I got in the Yum Extender - Powered by DNF:

```
g-io-error-quark: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Python.AttributeError: Traceback (most recent call last):  
File "/usr/lib64/python3.4/site-packages/dbus/service.py", line 707, in _message_cb retval = candidate_method(self, *args, **keywords)  
File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/dnfdaemon/server/init.py", line 83, in newFunc rc = func(*args, **kwargs)  
File "/usr/share/dnfdaemon/dnfdaemon-system", line 537, in RunTransaction result = self.run_transaction()  
File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/dnfdaemon/server/init.py", line 564, in run_transaction self._check_gpg_signatures(to_dnl)  
File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/dnfdaemon/server/init.py", line 713, in _check_gpg_signatures result, errmsg = self.base.sigCheckPkg(po)  
File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/dnf/util.py", line 79, in getattr % (C.name, name)) AttributeError: 'Base' object has no attribute 'sigCheckPkg' (36)
```

Other informations: Fedora 23, Mate desktop.

Enable repositories: fedora, updates, rpmfusion-free, rpmfusion-free-updates, rpmfusion-nonfree and rpmfusion-nonfree-updates

Comment: The answer of Argonauts works fine for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a recently discovered bug on F23 and F24 beta. The bug report can be found here [bugzilla.redhat.com](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1338564)

They have already posted a fix to the issue, which can be downloaded from here [koji.fedoraproject.org/](http://koji.fedoraproject.org/koji/buildinfo?buildID=768503)

Download the 3 non source files:

> dnfdaemon-0.3.16-1.fc23.noarch.rpm
>   python-dnfdaemon-0.3.16-1.fc23.noarch.rpm
>   python3-dnfdaemon-0.3.16-1.fc23.noarch.rpm

You need to install them using the dnf install command directly.
Assuming you downloaded them to your ~/Downloads folder, you would install them from the command line as follows:

```
cd ~/Downloads
sudo dnf install ./dnfdaemon-0.3.16-1.fc23.noarch.rpm ./python-dnfdaemon-0.3.16-1.fc23.noarch.rpm ./python3-dnfdaemon-0.3.16-1.fc23.noarch.rpm
```